# Relieving date of Current employer overlaps with joining date of future employer

Tags: employer-relations, india, notice-period, employer, relieving-letter

I work in the Indian IT sector. My last working date with my current employer falls on October 1st. Since the other company's annual cycle closes at the end of September and I was asked to join during the current cycle, I wanted to start with the new company on September 29th. I discussed this with HR at my current employer. HR agreed and asked me to take unpaid leave for the final 3 days and join the other company as per the planned date. However, HR mentioned that the final working date in the relieving letter needs to be be October 1st.

Since my last working date of current employer overlaps with the joining date of the new company (for 3 days), **will I face any problem going forward with future employers or Visa related issues for dual employment?**

My current HR said that this is a normal issue and I won't face any problem. I communicated this to the other company's HR as well and am waiting for her response. But in reality, what strategy should I follow to avoid any problems going forward?

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky situation. If you are asked to take leaves for the last 3 days, you will be expected to finish up your relieving formalities before you go on "leave" - which means you are officially out of the organization on this day. 
Why would you agree for a "leave" for the three days ? I think this is being complicated by your company HR. May be it is not a problem for your current company. But you will be answerable to your new company and any other future companies.

It is better to play it safe by stressing on getting relieved before 29th Sep or sacrifice on your "other" company.

Take care